# Error building C++ project in HaxeDevelop

Tags: c++, flashdevelop, haxelib, hxcpp

I use HaxeDevelop 5.2 and Haxe 3.4.2. I tried to build simple Hello world app in HaxeDevelop. But failed.

Here is the log:

Running process: C:\Program Files (x86)\HaxeDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "E:\temp\New Project14\New Project14.hxproj" -ipc 7de8e6ea-dcd6-4496-acea-c62337a09d79 -version "3.4.2" -compiler "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe" -notrace -library "C:\Program Files (x86)\HaxeDevelop\Library"

Building New Project14
haxe -cp src -cpp "E:/temp/New Project14/bin" -main Main

Unix.Unix_error(21, "open_proc", "haxelib path hxcpp")

Build halted with errors (haxe.exe).

Done(1).

What is the possible reason for this error? When I used the build command directly in the cmd.exe, it didn't fail. I've asked about this issue on github, but nobody has given any answer. FlashDevelop also failed.

Comment: See in your options if the path to executable is correct, or check if the executable folder is in `$PATH`

Comment: What executable do you mean?

Comment: If you build cop files there should be a compiler configured somewhere in your ide options